# Translate command line cURL to PHP

Tags: php, curl

When enter the following into my terminal

```
curl -F 'client_id=[clientID]' -F 'client_secret=[clientSecret]' -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' -F 'redirect_uri=[redirectURI]' -F 'code=[code]' https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

I get

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Invalid Client ID"}
```

But, when I try to achieve the same result using (all variables are set too. Just kind of unnecessary to include them)

```
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize";

$data = array('client_id' => '['.$client_id.']',
            'redirect_uri' => '['.$redirect_uri.']',
            'scope' => '[relationships]',
            'response_type' => '[code]');
//$fields = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

$c = curl_init();       
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$control = curl_exec($c);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($control);
echo '</pre>';
```

I get

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 18:56:59 GMT
Location: https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize
Server: nginx
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 18:56:59 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Location: https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/oauth/authorize
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=28c6b04e3e73745694d9fd4388acd8dd; expires=Tue, 03-Mar-2015 18:56:59 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: mid=UxYh-wAEAAFN3ZUutKcww23Vw_jd; expires=Mon, 27-Feb-2034 18:56:59 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/
Set-Cookie: ccode=US; Path=/
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 18:56:59 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 18:56:59 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=db8986eddf5ef57b2d080c7680ef614d; expires=Tue, 03-Mar-2015 18:56:59 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: mid=UxYh-wAEAAGxzegm0WQTbJBav8qr; expires=Mon, 27-Feb-2034 18:56:59 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/
Set-Cookie: ccode=US; Path=/
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 10841
Connection: keep-alive
```

Something seems to be off with the way I'm using cURL in my PHP code. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `-F` options correspond to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, not URL parameters.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to build a query string, use `http_build_query()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL will be:

```
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize";
```

For post parameter, do not use `http_build_query()` over the `$param` here as you are mimicking the `-F` of curl

```
$param = array(
    'client_id' => '[clientID]',
    'client_secret' => '[clientSecret]',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => '[redirectURI]', // you may need to urlencode() this one!
    'code' => '[code]'
);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
```

And this will help you to handle the `https` link.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

If you need more debugging, enable it:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Comment: I updated my answer and it still doesn't work even after taking your advice.

Comment: Told you, not to use `http_build_query`. Use the $data array directly into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. And it will work for you.

Comment: Updated again. That's what I get for the response now